# Does anyone make a round GPIO cable (flat ends obviously, rounded middle) see pic?

Tags: gpio, cable

Something like this floppy drive cable (which I think will not work because of wire swaps)
[image]

Comment: Those cables were just flat cable rolled up with a cover, ostensibly to improve airflow. If it is a 40 pin cable, it should work; only the floppy cables had crossovers.

Comment: Not that I know of but why would you need one. rounded cables are largely a cooling or aesthetic choice.